# Edit Visual Studio Code command palette entries

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to edit the file types shown on VS code command palette (Ctrl+P)?

E.g. I would like to hide the file types listed on my settings.json -> files.exclude not only from the left side file explorer but also from the command palette as well.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution with [JetBrains ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) - Navigate -> Go to file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
Hope someone will find a similar free solution.